# Структура PSD файла

Tags: javascript, photoshop

Возможно ли в `фотошопе` сделать `сценарий`, который запишет структуру файла в текстовый документ?
Например:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

— Слой 1

— Слой 2

— Группа 1

— — Слой 4

— — Группа 2

— — — Слой 5

— — Слой 3

Comment: На этом языке пишутся сценарии для фотошопа

Comment: Ну сама запись в файл у меня уже реализована. Сложность только в создании структуры. Не знаю с чего нужно начать.

Comment: Для этого надо знать структуру представления этих данных в фотошоп. Вы хотите историю модификаторов разных записать или со всеми данными слоев? Если растр со слоев сохранять, то вряд ли можно XML ил JSON отделаться.

Comment: Мне нужно только названия слоев и папок. А вообще я хочу из полученных данных сделать HTML код.